# Liferay First Time Login Portlet CSS Issue

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, liferay, portlet

I added a First Time Login portlet to Liferay. Then I added some CSS and jQuery code. It works very well on all the browsers but IE. The problem I'm having with IE is that it won't load the CSS and jQuery files. Basically what I mean is that when I run the portlet on IE there's no CSS style and interaction from jQuery. Again it works fine on all other browsers.

I'm testing on IE8. It only shows up in plain html format. No CSS style effects it. Unless I embed the css code in each html elements. THen it works fine. But i don't want to combine jsp and css files together.

Comment: which version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: You are by far too vague to give any clue for what might be the cause of your problem. "Something on IE doesn't work - what can it be?". Please rephrase your question and add more details.

Comment: If you used the same login for editing as asking your question, you wouldn't have to wait for it to be approved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this trick to "fix" css/js loading errors before that were unexplained on IE (other browsers too for that matter).

```
http://localhost:8080/?strip=0&js_fast_load=0
```

Substituting your host, port and portal context url of course.